# jstree - override cookies dependent on current url

Tags: cookies, navigation, href, jstree

I'm using jstree with a html UL, with each node being a href for navigation, which is included via php on each html page.

Jstree code is:

```
$(function(){
$("#treeview").jstree({
    "themes" : {
        "theme" : "default",
        "dots" : false,
        "icons" : false
    },
    "ui" : {
            "selected_parent_close" : "false",
            "select_multiple_modifier" : "false",
    },
    "core": { 
                "animation": 500
            },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui", "cookies" ]

});
$("#treeview").bind("reselect.jstree", function () {
    $("#treeview").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        document.location = data.rslt.obj.children("a").attr("href");
    });

}); 
});
```

Cookies work fine but the issue is in how to override the cookie selected node, when (and only when) the navigated url is one of the root nodes? If it is a root node, I want that to be open instead. This happens when navigating to the tree page from an external source or another page in the site with no tree, hence the cookie setting is not correct.

Am using jquery 1.7.2, jstree 1.0. All li id's are the same as the page name i.e. for href "page1" the relevant li id is "page1".

Answer (score 1):

The answer (or rather 'an' answer) is to 1) change cookie functionality by setting "save_selected" : false in the UI plugin; 2) set initially_select to the id of the page; 3) manually set the selected node as the final step using: $('#tree').jstree("select_node", $('body').attr('id'));